# find out how many weekend in a date range

Tags: php

for example I have two dates `2015-10-28` and `2015-12-31`. from these I want to know how many saturday and sunday in that given date range. I can find the diff between that dates but I can't find how many weekends.

anyone ever made this?

here is my current code:

```
function createDateRange($maxDate, $cell, $lead, $offArray = array()){
    $dates = [];
    --$cell;
    --$lead;

    $edate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($maxDate." -$lead day"));
    $sdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate." -$cell day"));

    $start = new DateTime($sdate);
    $end = new DateTime($edate);
    $end = $end->modify('+1 day');
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach($period as $d){
        $dt = $d->format('Y-m-d');
        if(!in_array($dt, $dates)){
            $dates[] = $dt;
        }
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

basically I want to add sat+sun count to the date range.

Comment: Loop through the dates and check the day. Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: @Sougata I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't know of any country that uses Saturday and Monday as weekend days. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @Bathsheba duh, sorry it was a bad typo @.@

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use an O(1)-type algorithm to solve this.

1. Given your starting date, move to the first Saturday. Call that `from`
2. Given your ending date, move back to the previous Friday. Call that `to`
3. Unless you have an edge case (where `to` is less than `from`), compute `(to - from) * 2 / 7` as the number of weekend days, and add that to any weekend days passed over in steps (1) and (2).

This is how I do it in production, although generalised for arbitrary weekend days.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
function getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates($startDate, $endDate, $weekdayNumber)
{
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);

    $dateArr = array();

    do
    {
        if(date("w", $startDate) != $weekdayNumber)
        {
            $startDate += (24 * 3600); // add 1 day
        }
    } while(date("w", $startDate) != $weekdayNumber);


    while($startDate <= $endDate)
    {
        $dateArr[] = date('Y-m-d', $startDate);
        $startDate += (7 * 24 * 3600); // add 7 days
    }

    return($dateArr);
}
```

**The function call to get dates for all Sunday's in year 2015:**

```
$dateArr = getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', 0);

print "<pre>";
print_r($dateArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //周日0 周一1 .....
  $data = 4;//周四

  $t1 ='2015-10-28';
  $t2 = '2015-12-31';
  $datetime1 = date_create($t1);
  $datetime2 = date_create($t2);
  $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
  $day = $interval->format('%a');

  $result = ($day)/7;
  $start = getdate(strtotime($t1))['wday'];
  $end = getdate(strtotime($t2))['wday'];

  if($data>=$start && $data<=$end){
    echo floor($result)+1;
  }else{
    echo floor($result);
  }
```